# Show that $E(Y|X)(\omega):=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}E(Y|X=x)\chi_{\left\{X=x\right\}}(\omega)$ is a discrete random variable

Tags: random-variables, conditional-expectation

> > Let $X,Y$ be two discrete, integrable random variables, which are defined on a probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$. Recall that the conditional expectation of $Y$ given $X=x$ is defined by
> >     $$
> > E(Y|X=x):=\sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)}yP(Y=y|X=x).
> > $$
> >     Show that
> >     $$
> > E(Y|X)(\omega):=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}E(Y|X=x)\chi_{\left\{X=x\right\}}(\omega)
> > $$
> >     defines a discrete random variable

Hello, I have one basic problem. I do not know what I have to show in order to show that
$$
E(Y|X)(\omega):=\sum_{x\in X(\Omega)}E(Y|X=x)\chi_{\left\{X=x\right\}}(\omega)
$$
defines a discrete random variable.

I think I have to show two things:

(1) $E(Y|X)$ is measurable (but: measurable in which sense?)

(2) $E(Y|X)(\Omega)$ is countable?

---

Comment: Recall the definition of a RV : measurable as a function from $\Omega$ to $E$ if $X:\Omega\rightarrow E$. Since you are working in discrete spaces, then the result is necessarily discrete, or am I missing something ?

Comment: $E(Y|X)\colon \Omega\to E$, but what is $E$?

Comment: The space of values of Y.Sorry misread

Comment: Why that?? Sorry cannot see that.

Comment: Look at the definition you gave of $E[Y|X=x]$. On the RHS you are multiplying y by real numbers and doing a sum... The value has to be of the same type than the y's...

Comment: But I do not think that $y\cdot P(Y=y|X=x)$ has to be in the values of Y.

Comment: You should. And what else could it be then ? If y is an element of $\mathbb{R}^d$, multiplying a vector by a real number gives a vector...

Comment: Okay, so $Y\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$? From what do I know that?

Comment: This is your exercise, I can't tell you. I guess that since it's integrable, you can work in $\mathbb{R}$ (I mean in a discrete subset of course since the RV are discrete)

Comment: One last question. Can $E(Y|X=x)$ be $\infty$?

Comment: No, your RV are integrable, meaning $E[|X|]<\infty$ and the same goes for $Y$

Comment: Hm, why does from $E(|Y|)<\infty$ follow, that $E(Y|X=x)<\infty$?

Comment: Because $|E(Y\mid X=x)|\leqslant E(|Y|)/P(X=x)$.

Comment: I only see $\lvert E(Y|X=x)\rvert\leqslant \sum_{y\in Y(\Omega)}\lvert y\rvert P(Y=y|X=x)$.

Comment: Yeah, because you did not even care to check.